# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HeaderUtils.createInbound()Ljakarta/ws/rs/core/AbstractMultivaluedMap;

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, backend

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HeaderUtils.createInbound()Ljakarta/ws/rs/core/AbstractMultivaluedMap;

[image]

If change the version jersey-common, other test cases are getting effected.

The dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-testing</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.42</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```